# ogr2ogr gdb to postgis -- empty geometry after import

Tags: postgis, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I am using the below command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -s_srs EPSG:2286 -t_srs EPSG:2286 PG:"host=${PGHOST} 
dbname=${PGDATABASE} user=${PGUSER}" import_file.gdb -overwrite -lco 
SCHEMA=some_schema -lco OVERWRITE=YES
```

The import runs without erros and I end up with features having a column

```
wkb_geometry geometry(Point,2286)
```

but there is never anything in it.
When I open the same file with FME Safe, I can see the points on the map, so I'm assuming the data has geometry info, but for some reason I'm not importing it?
I've imported gdb dumps in similar manner (from different sources) in the past and never had this issue before..

The output of

```
 ogrinfo -al -so some_dump.gdb
```

(ogrinfo -al some_dump.gdb) produces the same exact output

```
Layer name: SOME_LAYER_FEATURE
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 344
Extent: (1787446.125000, 496713.522000) - (2007796.551000, 958150.241000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Washington_South_FIPS_4602_Feet",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199432955]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",1640416.666666667],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-120.5],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",45.83333333333334],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",47.33333333333334],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",45.33333333333334],
    UNIT["Foot_US",0.304800609601219241]]
FID Column = OBJECTID
Geometry Column = SHAPE
FID: Real (0.0)
ORIENTATION: Real (0.0)
Z: Real (0.0)
```

I did just noticed that the line features DO contain geometries.. but the points do not.. even though I can see the points when opening the dump from FME.
I know the dump was generated through FME if that makes any difference..

Comment: Can GDAL find data from the .gdb? Test first with `ogrinfo -al -so import_file.gdb` and then without `-so`. Does ogrinfo list geometries?

Comment: Added the info above

Comment: `ogrinfo -al some_dump.gdb` should list the same layer info and then print all attributes including the geometry for each 344 points.

Comment: oh I see -- yes, looking at records there is no geometry info listed for points, but I can see geometry for line features (and can see them in the database).  Does this mean something is wrong with the dump?

Comment: It feels that gdb is somehow special. If the data are not confidential create a small test gdb and write mail to GDAL-dev mailing list. Perhaps some developer has time to analyze why points are invisible for GDAL.

Comment: confidential data.. so the fact that I can see the points if I open the dump in FME? Does that mean anything at all?

Comment: The GDAL OpenFileGDB driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html is reverse engineered and there can well be some features which are not known to the driver yet. But check if your gdb is compressed, that is documented to be unsupported. If db is not compressed it would be nice to create a test gdb with the same process from some non-confidential point data.